# add / remove field dynamically in php mysql without javascript

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on student database. Each Applicant can apply for upto three programs. I want to include add / remove program option on my php form without using javascript. Is it possible to do it wihout javascript?
please help!!!

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: No , Javascript is necessary

Comment: What do you think is not possible?  What are you struggling with specifically?

Comment: Yes it is. But you'll have to reload the page on every action and provide server side logic for each possibility.

Comment: @Saturnix It's not `dynamic` in web meaning if you reload webpage.

Comment: @Elon Than That's not at all true, a dynamic page is just one that changes based on user input, [all the logic can happen server side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page). So if the server applies logic based on a user selecting a form, that's dynamic. Static means there's no logic outside of routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP only executes at runtime, ie when the page first loads. To do this, you'd need to reload the page every time you wanted a change to the page. So what I see is you have the first page they land on offer a form for the user to choose which of your three programs they're interested in, when the form submits, the page reloads and the server - queuing off the user's selection - loads and displays the appropriate program form.

If you want to do it without reloading the page, it is not possible without JavaScript as PHP cannot execute without talking to the server.

Here's an example of a form that at first displays a question to the user, posts to itself, then conditionally displays a field based on the user's input:

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['program'])) : ?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    Should we show the program field?<br>
    <input type="radio" value="y" name="program" id="program_y"><label for="program_y">Yes</label><br>
    <input type="radio" value="n" name="program" id="program_n"><label for="program_n">No</label><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php else : ?>
<form method="POST" action="form_submit_url_here">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" id="name"><br>
    <?php if ($_POST['program'] === 'y') : ?>
    <label for="program_name">Name of your program:</label>
    <input type="text" name="program_name" id="program_name"><br>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i dont mind reloading page everytime. i just want to know how will this be done? only one field called "program", needs to be added dynamically. i am avoiding javasript as many people these days disable it.

Comment: "many people these days disable it. " As a general, statement, this isn't true any more. 5 years ago, it was a valid concern, but is not true these days. The only time I worry about progressive enhancement is if projects specifications or analytics tell me I need to worry about it. I updated my answer with some code to demonstrate the non-JavaScript behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can do simple form to add info to Database with Submit Button that's for adding . For Deleting you can make Delete page that GET user id that you want to delete .

Comment: ok. Thanks for your help. i am just going to write a code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **you can't**.

PHP requires information to be processed either by that page or by another, and therefore data needs to be sent. Javascript (using AJAX) can be used to send that data from the page without a page refresh or relocation.

Comment: but what if your client disables javascript?

Comment: Then you should enable it again. All major browsers and operating systems accept Javascript and more and more websites are being built utilising it, making the end-user-experience more seamless instead of constantly redirecting them through pages.

Comment: Depending on your client base, you can't necessarily require JavaScript. It's all about the project specifications, sometimes you can't force modern technology. Ex: internal web apps where the company is using old Windows 2k with IE and JS disabled. It sucks, but it happens.